# Using WCF Data Services to copy one database table to another

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, wcf

I am little stuck in using LINQ to insert one database table to another database table located on another server as a WCF Data Service.

Suppose I have an Item class on the local database and the same Item class on the the remote server, and I want to copy all the records across.

Is there a possibility to do this from: -

private Uri svcUri = new Uri("someurl/WcfDataService.svc");
Entities = new Entities(svcUri);

.....

I know that LINQ to SQL is mostly a 1-1 mapping between classes and the database, but I heard it is possible.

Comment: mysql already supporting for database replication why you do not go with that ?

Comment: I am not 100% using database replication.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to construct a connectionstring pointing at the right database. That database has to have the tables the EF expects to have though. (The code would look like yours, but I've never used a Uri for a connection string.)

However, it would be more efficient to do via a stored procedure on your source database, via a Linked Database to y=the Target. This because if you do it via WCF the data has to travel twice: SourceDB -> WCF service -> TargetDB, whereas with a SP it only has one hop: SourceDB -> TargetDB. Also in the SP it will operate pretty much as a set operation whereas the WCF service will have to process one row at a time.

EDIT - Apologies: I didn't notibe the MySQL tag. I don't know whether MySQL supports Linked Databases, so feel free to ignore this if it doesn't.

Comment: Hi Simon, linked database will work on this but I need to have this as a web service because it isn't just one database connecting to the remote machine. There will seperate machines (clients) linking to the same remote database machine so all the connection strings will be different.